# I have an error for naturals number program

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple program naturals number and the input is given by the user..when the increment is proceed that's had error in n=n +1.and the error is can't convert int object to str implicity

Comment: add your some code snippet here

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check out [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)